# knockout observableArray access

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I send OptionsServer to Server correctly ? Cause I'm trying to send values from checked Checkbox to server.

My code:

```
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.ui = {};

viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport = {
    ChoosenEmails : ko.observableArray(),
    ChoosenOptions : ko.observableArray(),
    OptionsServer :  ko.observableArray(),
    Options : ko.observableArray([ "New Contacts", "Updated Contacts","Verified Contacts" ]),
    OptionsToSend: ko.computed({
        read : function () {
            var viewModelShortcut= viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport;
            if (viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()=="New Contacts")
                viewModelShortcut.OptionsServer.push('NEW');  
             else if (viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()=="Updated Contacts")    
                 viewModelShortcut.OptionsServer.push('BETTER'); 
             else if (viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()=="Verified Contacts")  
                 viewModelShortcut.OptionsServer.push('NOT_BETTER');  
        /*   else if (viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()[0]=="New Contacts" 
                     && viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()[1]=="Updated Contacts" 
                     && viewModelShortcut.ChoosenOptions()[2]=="Verified Contacts")
                 viewModelShortcut.OptionsServer.push('NEW','BETTER','NOT_BETTER'); 
        */      
},
    deferEvaluation: true
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it works :

```
OptionsToSend: ko.computed({
    read : function () {
          console.info(viewModel.ui.Report.Options()[0]);
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
})
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6HpQZ/)

Comment: can u help me again for my Options to send for server ?

I have 3 checkboxes : New contacts, updated contacts, verified contacts

And I would like to send the correct values to my server but if the user check, uncheck checkbox my OptionsServer array is not edited...

Comment: I will be glad to help you again.
But, I think this is another question.
In order to help people that are facing the same problem, consider to close this question and create anther one.